# Can electricity distribution transformers increase lightning surge current from 30 kA to 1500 kA?

Tags: surge-protection, lightning, mov

I read somewhere that an average lightning strike is about 30 kiloamperes and lasts for a duration of 30 microseconds (but it may consist of number of sub-flashes so the total duration may be 0.2 seconds from first sub-flash to last sub-flash).

I'm trying to understand what this means for lightning protection with metal oxide varistors (MOVs): how many Joules rating is sufficient?

Let's assume I'm at 230 volt grid and that a typical MOV intended for surge suppression at 230 volts clamps at 500 volts.

If we consider a MOV that has to withstand 30 kiloamperes for 30 microseconds at 500 volts, the total energy is:

```
500 V * 30000 A * 30e-6 s = 450 J
```

So far, so good. Even a basic lightning protector should handle that. Of course a single lightning flash can be larger than 450 Joules, that was just the average, but it's easy to find MOV-based devices capable of dissipating over 2500 Joules.

However, this was assuming the lightning hit the low-voltage 230 volt wiring at my house. I'm not entirely sure if this is a realistic scenario since the house has a lightning rod and the 230 volt wiring should be buried underground. However, nearby there are electrical wires hanging in the air that distribute the electricity at much higher voltage, and if a lightning hits the electrical system it definitely hits those high-voltage wires.

I'm not completely sure what's the voltage of those wires, but a good assumption would be 20 kilovolts (three-phase; if I understand correctly this corresponds to `20000 V / sqrt(3) = 11547 V` RMS for a single phase).

So if I'm using electricity at 230 V, and the distribution happens at 11547 V, the voltage is reduced by a factor of 50. Doesn't this mean that current is increased by a factor of 50?

So is it realistic that a lightning hits this high-voltage network, causing a current of 30 kiloamperes at high voltage, and the transformer between this high-voltage network and my house increases this current by a factor of 50, causing a current of `30 kA * 50 = 1500 kA` through my lightning protection devices? This would mean that 450 Joules is not sufficient but that I would need to have 22500 Joule rated devices which I can't find anywhere for sale.

Or is there some mechanism such as transformer saturation that would actually mean that it's impossible to get a 1500 kA surge directly at my house?

Would for example limited insulation and wire resistance limit the surge current? If I'm assuming there's 25 meter live wire and 25 meter neutral wire side by side, both 2.5 mm<sup>2</sup>, from transformer to surge protector, there should be about 0.35 Ohm resistance total. If insulator breaks down at 25000 volts / mm, and each wire has 0.7 mm insulation, total breakdown should be 35000 volts. 35000 volts and 0.35 Ohm should give 100 kA surge max, shouldn't it?

At least lightning has enough energy for a 1500 kA surge: I read that a typical lightning flash has 300 million volts, so stepping it down 50:1 means there's still 6 million volts left.

Comment: Direct lightning strikes will kill any protection device within reason. You should be considering indirect lightning strikes as per EN 61000-4-5. That document allows you to pick and choose a TVS.

Comment: I have several books on the shelf on this topic: *"The Art and Science of Lightning Protection"* by Marton Uman; *"NFPA 780 Standard for the Installation of Lightning Protection Systems -- 2020 edition"* by NFPA; *"Lightning Physics and Lightning Protection"* by Bazelyan and Raizer; and *"Grounding and Bonding for the Radio Amateur: Good Practices for Electrical Safety, Lightning Protection, and RF Management"* by H. Ward Silver. The first one mentioned is the first one I read. I liked it. The rest add bits and pieces. Also, contact your power supplier. They have expert experience.